# Objective-c BOOL always passing

Tags: ios, objective-c

How do I check for true or false as this is NOT

```
 BOOL *isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kSignedInBool];
BOOL *userSignedUp = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kHasUserEverSignedUpBool];

if(userSignedUp == NO || isLoggedIn == NO) { // they don't have an account so can't sign in.

    //Show the modal opening screen path

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showOpeningScreen" sender:self];

} else { //

    // We have signed up before so findNearbyamulanes
    [self performSelector:@selector(findNearByAmbulances) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You shouldn't be using a pointer with a primitive data type.

Change `BOOL *` to `BOOL`.

EDIT: Obligatory [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-pJlnpkLp0) to a (somewhat ridiculous, but useful) video on pointers.

Comment: This may not solve the problem (though it is absolutely correct). If not, confirm that you are calling `synchronize` where ever you are setting the boolean value into the user defaults.